# Problem with Linq to Entities query

Tags: linq-to-entities

first I'll thanks any of your help in this matter.
I'm doing this query (Linq to Entities)

public override IEnumerable Execute(UserGroup userGroup)
        {

```
        return from a in _ctx.Activities.OfType<ResourceActivity>()
               where userGroup.Users.Contains(a.User)
               group a by new { a.User, a.Href } into fg
               select new UserResourceActivityReturnValue
               {
                   UserDBIdentity = fg.Key.User.DbId,
                   UserIdentity = fg.Key.User.Id,
                   UserName = fg.Key.User.Name,
                   ResourceName = fg.Key.Href,
                   ResourceAccess = fg.Count()
               };
```

And I have this error:

"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Data.User'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."

So I change it to this:

public override IEnumerable Execute(UserGroup userGroup)
        {

```
        return from a in _ctx.Activities.OfType<ResourceActivity>()
               from u in userGroup.Users
               where a.User.DbId == u.DbId
               group a by new { a.User, a.Href } into fg
               select new UserResourceActivityReturnValue
               {
                   UserDBIdentity = fg.Key.User.DbId,
                   UserIdentity = fg.Key.User.Id,
                   UserName = fg.Key.User.Name,
                   ResourceName = fg.Key.Href,
                   ResourceAccess = fg.Count()
               };
```

And I keep seeing the same error, please help.

My email is aalbalat@uclv.edu.cu

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

The fix to your original query:

```
return from a in _ctx.Activities.OfType<ResourceActivity>()
        where userGroup.Users.Any(arg => arg.DbId == a.User.DbId)
        group a by 
            new
            {
                UserId = a.User.Id, 
                UserDbId = a.User.DbId, 
                UserName =  a.User.Name, 
                a.Href
            } into fg
        select new UserResourceActivityReturnValue
        {
            UserDBIdentity = fg.Key.UserDbId,
            UserIdentity = fg.Key.UserId,
            UserName = fg.Key.User.UserName,
            ResourceName = fg.Key.Href,
            ResourceAccess = fg.Count()
        };
```

The problem is that you were using `User` entity in `Contains` and in `GroupBy`.